# Hyperledger Composer - Chaincode: Premature execution

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i'm facing a problem with Hyperledger Composer v0.18.1 running on IBM Cloud Platform.
I have been able to deploy the chaincode to the network, but after one day of inactivity if i try to ping the network i get this error:

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: premature execution - chaincode (:0.18.1) is being launched

I tried to restart the peers and also the CA, but it didn't help.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see ANSWERS here (incl comments in answer 2)   -> https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/441724/unable-to-add-new-participants-to-a-deployed-busin/

including a link to the support page there.